# yii2 active field template

Tags: activerecord, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, active-form

It seems template for checkbox in sample yii2 project doesn't not apply correctly

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe', [
    'template' => "<div class=\"col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
])->checkbox() ?>
```

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 17):

You need to pass template like in this example

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')
->checkbox(
['template' => '<div class="form-group">{input}<label class="control-label">{label}</label></div>']
) ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sad, that people add - to this great answer. This works great!

But you have to switch `\yii\widget\ActiveForm class to \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm`

So:

```
\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm:beginForm();

echo $form->field($model, 'terms_condition',['checkboxTemplate'=>"<div class=\"checkbox\">\n{input}
{beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n</div>"])->checkbox(['value'=>true])

\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm:endForm();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'terms_condition',['checkboxTemplate'=>"<div class=\"checkbox\">\n{input}
{beginLabel}\n{labelTitle}\n{endLabel}\n{error}\n{hint}\n</div>"])->checkbox(['value'=>true]) ?>
```

use this code